# Compare and filter multiple rows based on their unique id

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that the structure is:

```
id status submissions date
 1 offline 1          2017
 1 online  2          2018
 1 online  3          2006
 2 offline 1          2006
 2 online  4          2018
 2 online  2          2002
 2 online  5          2004
```

My problem is that for each id, rows with higher submissions should have a date >= than the
previous one. how can i filter the dataframe in order to have:

```
 id status  submissions  date
 1 offline           1  2017
 1 online            2  2018
 2 offline           1  2006
 2 online            4  2018
```

Ive tried to use `dplyr group_by()` and then `filter()` but it doesnt work.

Comment: Why is row 7 not included in your desired output? Both submissions and date are greater than on row 6.

Comment: Because row 7 has more submissions  than row 4 and the date is smaller than row 4

Comment: To make it more, for each id the rows should be compared against the offline one and filtered on the conditions mentioned above! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse solution which doesn't use filter but gets the correct output:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
status <- c("offline","online","online","offline","online","online","online")
date <- c(2017,2018,2006,2006,2018,2002,2004)
tibble(id,status,date)

df %>%
    group_by(id, status) %>%
    arrange(desc(date)) %>%
    summarize(date = first(date))
```

It should yield you:

```
 A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
     id status   date
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 offline  2017
2     1 online   2018
3     2 offline  2006
4     2 online   2018
```

I think this is a slightly easier logical flow but that is completely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1 | submissions > first(submissions) & date >= first(date))

     id status  submissions  date
  <int> <chr>         <int> <int>
1     1 offline           1  2017
2     1 online            2  2018
3     2 offline           1  2006
4     2 online            4  2018
```

It assumes that `offline` status is always the first row per group.

Or a possibility for a scenario when `offline` status is not the first row per group:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 arrange(status, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1 | submissions > first(submissions) & date >= first(date))
```